# JRE version on solaris + Invalid argument when runing JRE java

Tags: java, solaris

I located the Jre1.6 in my Solaris machine under /tmp
in order to use the Jre version

```
pwd
/tmp


 ls -ltr jre1.6
 total 512
 -r--r--r--   1 root     root         917 Oct  3  2011 Welcome.html
 -r--r--r--   1 root     root      183173 Oct  3  2011    THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
 -r--r--r--   1 root     root          46 Oct  3  2011 README
 -r--r--r--   1 root     root          40 Oct  3  2011 LICENSE
 -r--r--r--   1 root     root        3339 Oct  3  2011 COPYRIGHT
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         117 Oct 25  2011 javaws
 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root        1024 Nov  4  2012 bin
 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         242 Nov  4  2012 plugin
 drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         246 Nov  4  2012 man
 drwxr-xr-x  18 root     root        4655 Nov  4  2012 lib
```

but when I run it as the follwijg:

```
 /tmp/jre1.6/bin/java -jar ll.jar ……
 /tmp/jre1.6/bin/java: Invalid argument.
```

I get Invalid argument.

what need to do in order to run the java ( only under /tmp ) , without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Invalid argument" when running a Solaris binary often means you installed a version for the wrong architectures - a SPARC binary on an x86 platform or an x86 binary on a SPARC platform.

Run `uname -p` to see what processor type your system has and make sure you downloaded Java for that type of CPU.